# Contact form Not Working Keeps Giving Me Array

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, contacts

So I have this contact script which works great in firefox but whenever anyone tries it in ie 7 or 8 the plan always returns array and for the life of me I cant figure out what I did wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

  if(!$_POST) exit;

    $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $phone    = $_POST['phone'];
    $cname    = $_POST['cname'];
    $address1    = $_POST['address'];
    $address2    = $_POST['address2'];
    $city    = $_POST['city'];
    $state    = $_POST['state'];
    $zip    = $_POST['zip'];
    $plan   = $_POST['plan'];
    $verify   = $_POST['verify'];

    if(trim($name) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($email) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($phone) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(!is_numeric($phone)) {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Phone number can only contain digits.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(!isEmail($email)) {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
        exit();
    }
    if(trim($cname) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your Company Name.</div>';
        exit();
    } 
    if(trim($address1) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your Address.</div>';
        exit();
    }
    if(trim($city) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your city.</div>';
        exit();
    }
    if(trim($state) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your state.</div>';
        exit();
    }
    if(trim($zip) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter your zip code.</div>';
        exit();
    }
    else if(trim($verify) == '') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter the verification number.</div>';
        exit();
    } else if(trim($verify) != '4') {
        echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
        exit();  
    }


    if($error == '') {

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $comments = stripslashes($comments);
        }


     // Configuration option.
     // Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
     // Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

     $address = "email@email.com";


     // Configuration option.
     // i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

     // Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

     $e_subject = 'Veterans Career Fair: You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


     // Configuration option.
     // You can change this if you feel that you need to.
     // Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

     $e_body = "You have been contacted by $name from $cname, they wish to sign up for the $plan Plan. Their additional information is as follows:\r\n\n";
     $e_reply = "Contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone. \r\n\n";
     $e_mail =  "Address of $name is: $address1 $address2, $city, $state $zip";

     $msg = $e_body . $e_reply . $e_mail;

     if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n")) {


     // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

     echo "<fieldset>";         
     echo "<div id='success_page'>";
     echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
     echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
     echo "<p>You should hear from us in 48 hours</p>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "</fieldset>";

     } else {

     echo 'ERROR!';

     }

}

   function isEmail($email) { // Email address verification, do not edit.

   return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));

    }
    ?>
```

The Html

```
            <form method="post" action="bin/sendme.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" /><br />
                <label>Email</label>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" /><br />
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" value="" /><br />                      
                <label>Company Name</label>
                <input name="cname" type="text" id="cname" size="30" value="" /><br />                      
                <label>Address 1</label>
                <input name="address" type="text" id="address" size="30" value="" /><br />                      
                <label>Address 2</label>
                <input name="address2" type="text" id="address2" size="30" value="" /><br />                        
                <label>City</label>
                <input name="city" type="text" id="city" size="30" value="" /><br />                        
                <label>State</label>
                <input name="state" type="text" id="state" size="30" value="" /><br />                      
                <label>Zip Code</label>
                <input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" size="30" value="" /><br />
                <label>Plan</label>
                <select name="plan" type="text" id="plan">
                    <option value="Platinum">Platinum Sponsorship</option>
                    <option value="Gold">Gold Sponsorship</option>
                    <option value="Silver">Silver Sponsorship</option>
                    <option value="Survey">Survey Sponsorship</option>  
                    <option value="Marquee">Marquee Sponsorship</option>                            
                </select>   
                <label>3 + 1 =</label>
                <input name="verify" type="text" id="verify" size="4" value="" style="width: 30px;" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="REGISTER NOW" /> 
            </form>
```

The Jquery

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#message').hide();

    $('#submit')
        .after('<img src="assets/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');

    $.post(action, { 
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        cname: $('#cname').val(),
        address: $('#address').val(),
        city: $('#city').val(),
        state: $('#state').val(),
        zip: $('#zip').val(),
        plan: $('#plan').val(),
        verify: $('#verify').val()
    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled',''); 
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

        }
    );

    });

    return false; 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<select name="plan" type="text" id="plan">`
should be 
`<select name="plan" id="plan">`

Answer (score 1):

The html `select` element does not have an attribute `type` so perhaps that's confusing IE